# Calling functions from separate view controllers in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates, viewcontroller

I think the solution to this is going to need to use delegation, but I'm unfamiliar with how to use them.
So in my project, I have my main `viewcontroller/storyboard` that contains a `UIScrollView`. That `UIScrollview` calls another storyboard (`xib file`) as a subview. The other storyboard (which is an `xib file`) is controlled with another swift file.

My question is, when I call an action inside of my other storyboard, how can I call a function from the main `viewcontroller`. Like say the `viewdidload` from the first `viewcontroller`. 
I can't make the whole thing a global function, it needs to stay inside its class. So if I try to do `ViewController.viewDidLoad()` it needs (I think) an instance variable or something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. Using weak variable (property) in the other class with type UIViewController
2. Assign the parent view controller to that property after the other view is initialized

Good reads about weak, strong, unowned references [Here](http://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift) And [Here](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/05/08/strong-weak-and-unowned-sorting-out-arc-and-swift/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you want to call it with class name as you said above declare your method with "`class`". So its just like static in Java. It makes it generic to call it anywhere in your project. Make a separate extension.

```
class func myfunc(){
}
```

if you want to send data from B to A controller. You use what is called delegation. You give the work of B to A. Make a protocol above B for functions that you want to do or send with them. Call them in B. And then in A write code for those functions. So that you have the data from B to A

Else you demand something like common data. Create a singleton class and initialize properties methods there. You can use objects for that and call it in other controller to modify or make different instances.

You dont call `viewDidLoad()`. As the name says it loads once. If you want something that modify everytime you screen appears, use `viewWillAppear`

Comment: I know I can do that to make a method static. But in my case, the method I want to call that would need to be static needs to have a UIScrollview connected to it. Which can't happen if its not in a class. Right? I'm not sure how to get around that.